# What is the best way to insert large lists into a SQL database? [ANDROID]

Tags: java, android, sql, database, list

Here is what i am trying to do, i have created a SQL database to hold a giant table of drinks,  The table looks like this:

```
    **_ID    ALCOHOL   TYPE    BRAND    PRICE**
```

Ex.     1        Liquor    Vodka   Smirnoff   14

Here is the code for my database adapter:

```
    package net.learn2develop.Database;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_ALCOHOL = "alcohol";
public static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";
public static final String KEY_BRAND = "brand";
public static final String KEY_PRICE = "price";
private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "booze";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "titles";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table titles (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "alcohol text not null, type text not null, " 
    + "brand text not null);" + "price integer not null";

private final Context context;

private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
                          int newVersion) 
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
              + " to "
              + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS titles");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

  //---opens the database---
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

//---closes the database---    
public void close() 
{
    DBHelper.close();
}

//---insert a title into the database---
public long insertTitle(String alcohol, String type, String brand, int price) 
{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_ALCOHOL, alcohol);
    initialValues.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
    initialValues.put(KEY_BRAND, brand);
    initialValues.put(KEY_PRICE, price);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

//---deletes a particular title---
public boolean deleteTitle(long rowId) 
{
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + 
            "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

//---retrieves all the titles---
public Cursor getAllTitles() 
{
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
            KEY_ROWID, 
            KEY_ALCOHOL,
            KEY_TYPE,
            KEY_BRAND,
            KEY_PRICE}, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null);
}

//---retrieves a particular title---
public Cursor getTitle(long rowId) throws SQLException 
{
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                    KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_ALCOHOL, 
                    KEY_TYPE,
                    KEY_BRAND,
                    KEY_PRICE
                    }, 
                    KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, 
                    null,
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

//---updates a title---
public boolean updateTitle(long rowId, String alcohol, 
String type, String brand, int price) 
{
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_ALCOHOL, alcohol);
    args.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
    args.put(KEY_BRAND, brand);
    args.put(KEY_PRICE, price);
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, 
                     KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

}
```

Now I know I could add them individually in my main activity by calling:

```
    //---add 2 titles---
    db.open();        
    long id;
    id = db.insertTitle(
            "Liquor",
            "Vodka",
            "Smirnoff",
                    "14");        
    id = db.insertTitle(
            "Liquor",
            "Rum",
            "Captain Morgan",
                    "20");
    db.close();
```

The problem is i have hundreds to add.... what is the best way to go about adding them all into the DB?
Thanks in advance for anyhelp you guys! I am still learning, i have never used a database before so im lost rite now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend hard coding them in your source, since you will have double the data (and then some) and will suck RAM and storage from your users.

I assume that there is no good reason for you to statically load the list into your DB at runtime. I also assume that you already have the list of drinks.

I would create a CSV file from the list and then use a desktop SQLite editor on my PC to load the list into my table(s), then include the database as a resource in my app.

Google will lead you to plenty of SQLite editors.

I do all of my DB design and initial loading/testing on my PC before moving it to Android.  It's a lot easier and faster.

Good luck.

Comment: Is there a tutorial you could point me toward on how to do all of this? you are exactly rite though, i would like to hardcode all of the options and I do already have a list of the drinks, the only reason im asking for a tutorial is because i have never worked with a DB before lol

Comment: For PC editing, I use SQLite Database Browser - open source and on SourceForge.  It's really quite easy to begin.  Think of a database table like a spreadsheet sheet where you have columns and rows.  The database is similar to the spreadsheet with multiple sheets (tables) (good lord, just had a Lotus 1-2-3 flashback).  Simply create the DB and your drinks table with column names and types to match the CSV (no spaces in column names, case matters and look out for apostrophes in the data).  Try starting here http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki/wiki?p=ImportingFiles

Comment: Thanks a ton! should I just use the existing DB that i have already created? and if so how do i extract it out of my application project?

Comment: If your phone is rooted, you can browse to /data/data/<your app>/databases and copy the DB out.

Comment: what if my phone isnt rooted? would it be easier just to create a whole new DB?

Comment: And when i try to import my .csv into my new table nothing happens? i hit create and nothing happens at all?

Comment: If you're using SQLite Database Browser on Windows, be careful with line endings and encodings -use a text editor to edit your CSV and encode as UTF8 with no BOM and Unix line endings, e.g. Notepad++.  Or, try SQLite Admin http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/.

Comment: Got it! Apparently the .CSV wont import if excel is still open? anyway, I have the DB all created now how do I import it back into my project inplace of the other?

Comment: Pleased it worked.  Time for the University of Google now.  Not appropriate to continue on SO in comments.  Check this out, http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/.  Please accept my answer and good luck with your app.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();

db.beginTransaction();
try {   
    for(ContentValues con:conValues){
    db.insert(TABLE_COLUMN,null,con);
}
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} 
    finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

You can read more about begintransaction and end transaction [SQLite Optimization in Android](http://www.android-app-market.com/sqlite-optimization-in-android-programming-sqlite-optimization-in-android-apps.html)